# Once email Id is verified, show expired message for next time

Tags: java, liferay

After registration, system send a verification mail to subscriber's mail id.

When user once clicks on verification link, the token must be expired.

I want to display the link expired message from next time click?

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may override VerifyEmailAddressAction.java action class, and set custom error message in SessionErrors and display it in Email Verification screen.

Comment: should i have to make hook for that?

Comment: Yes @Akash ! REFER:https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/customize-and-extend-functionality-hooks-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for the pointer, Struts action can be overridden but I don't know how do we override a Liferay Action class? Thanks

Comment: @PankajKathiriya i have my custom DL portlet. which use to display multiple document! can i add rating portlet for each document?